# How do make `ido-find-file` work for file location with relative path?

Tags: emacs, ido

Say the current directory is `/abc`, and I wish I could open `/abc/def/file.txt` with the following steps:

1. Invoke `ido-find-file`
2. In the mini-buffer (prompting `/abc`), I **paste** (`yank`) `def/file.txt`
3. Hit enter.

If it were `find-file`, it would open `file.txt`, but not `ido-find-file`.
Any hacking to make `ido-find-file` follow the behavior of `file-file`?

Answer (score 1):

This has been wondered before, and this seems to be closest to the solution you're looking for: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5411

Based on your use case, you may be better off using `find-file-at-point`.